# Can't Find Gradle Workers Module?

Tags: windows, gradle

I'm trying to set up a fresh gradle environment for our build server, but I seem to be missing some module or jar that's meant to come with an install. I've done a clean install three times, so what would cause the module "gradle-workers" to not be found?

Environment: Windows Server 2012 R2

```
> 12:57:27.432 org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException:
> Could not create service of type ClassLoaderRegistry using
> GlobalScopeServices.createClassLoaderRegistry(). 12:57:27.433     at
> org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:807)
> 12:57:27.433  at
> org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:761)
> 12:57:27.433  at
> org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:598)
> 12:57:27.433  at
> org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:643)
> 12:57:27.434  at
> org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.applyConfigureMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:253)
> 12:57:27.434  at
> org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.findProviderMethods(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:214)
> 12:57:27.434  at
> org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.addProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:352)
> 12:57:27.435  at
> org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.build(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:52)
> 12:57:27.435  at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.BuildActionsFactory.createGlobalClientServices(BuildActionsFactory.java:148)
> 12:57:27.435  at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.BuildActionsFactory.runBuildWithDaemon(BuildActionsFactory.java:108)
> 12:57:27.435  at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.BuildActionsFactory.createAction(BuildActionsFactory.java:83)
> 12:57:27.435  at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.createAction(CommandLineActionFactory.java:249)
> 12:57:27.437  at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
> 12:57:27.437  at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:217)
> 12:57:27.437  at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:33)
> 12:57:27.437  at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
> 12:57:27.438  at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
> 12:57:27.438  at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
> 12:57:27.438  at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
> 12:57:27.438  at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
> 12:57:27.439  at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
> 12:57:27.439  at
> org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
> 12:57:27.439  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) 12:57:27.439  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> 12:57:27.440  at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> 12:57:27.440  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> 12:57:27.453  at
> org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
> 12:57:27.453  at
> org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
> 12:57:27.454  at
> org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23) 12:57:27.454
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.UnknownModuleException:
> Cannot locate JAR for module 'gradle-workers' in distribution
> directory 'D:\apps\gradle-3.4.1'.
```